# CF7 need to send two different mail

Tags: wordpress, email

I've created a form with contact form 7, and I need to send two e-mails, one with all the data that I pick up from the form, another one with a "thank you" message and other important information, these informations are statics, all the same for every user that clicks in the submit button.

So my problem is this email, CF7 can send only one type of mail to multiple users, but not two differents mail to two differents users. The second mail needs to use the [your-mail] (the mail that the users write in the form).

I've discovered the on_sent_ok function that allows me to open a page or something else after the submit, but I have no idea how to send this different mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while from your request, but I write here my solution for future needs.

You can reach the goal by following 2 steps:

**A)** handle the sent mail Contact Form 7 event.

```
    function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
        $title = $contact_form->title;
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        if ($submission && "New hospital" == $title) {
            $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
            //$posted_data is an associative array that contains all the form input values,
            //so you can use it to proceed with B step
       }
    }

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_mail_sent_event_triggered' );
```

If you're not sure on where place this code my suggestion is to add it at the beginning of your theme's function.php file.

**B)** send a custom mail using [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) API.
If you take a look at the docs you'll find that the API is quite easy to understand.

```
$to = 'sendto@example.com';
$subject = 'The subject';
$body = 'The email body content';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Obviously you can customize the body message using or not the `$posted_data` values according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've not tried your reply because I've done this thing with other technique but hope that it might be helpful for someone else!